# Different AndroidManifest content depending on Android API Level

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-api-30

Is it possible to include meta-data in my Android Manifest file for only a specific API level?

I want the following line only be considered when the app is built on a phone with Android API >= 30:

```
    <meta-data android:name="disable_batch_scanning" android:value="true"  />
```

I tried to set a boolean variable under res/values/bools.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isLess31">true</bool>
</resources>
```

And use it with the tag: `android:enabled="@bool/isLess31"`
Therefore, I also created a values-v31 folder where is set `isLess31` to `false`

But this does not seem to work.
Is there another way that `disable_batch_scanning` is only executed for older Android APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is this:

Create file used for default values.

```
res/values/bool.xml

<resources>
    <bool name="disable_batch_scanning_variable">true</bool>
</resources>
```

And also create one for specific value. This one will be used for APIs equal to 31 and above.

```
res/values-v31/bool.xml

<resources>
    <bool name="disable_batch_scanning_variable">false</bool>
</resources>
```

In Android Manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="disable_batch_scanning" android:value="@bool/disable_batch_scanning_variable"  />
```

Comment: I am just not sure, if I really understand the concept with largeHeap.. Can you please explain?

Comment: I have improved the answer, so check it out again. LargeHeap is irrelevant, I gave you bad example.